# Why does passing 0 to the radix of parseInt in Javascript return decimal values?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following expression

```js
console.log( 'result: ' + parseInt("1", 0) )
```

It returns 1 in the console of chrome (basically returns the decimal value).

The [MDN docs for parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) says

> Or NaN when the radix is smaller than 2 or bigger than 36 ...

It would be great if someone could give an explanation for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDN is summarizing the specification, and is not complete.

The actual [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/global-object.html#sec-parseint-string-radix) says:

> If *radix* is `undefined` or 0, it is assumed to be 10 except when the number begins with the code unit pairs `0x` or `0X`, in which case a radix of 16 is assumed.

Comment: Thank you. I also found a similar answer here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description 
Turns out, I had to read further down. LOL.